# Make a column scrollable in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can i make a column with many other things in it scrollable

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[..
```

Comment: Replace expanded with a container of fixed size and wrap the column in SingleChildScrollView

Comment: when i do this is affecting all my view and it shows just a white screen

Comment: Did you place the stack in a container with fixed size?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

Comment: when i do this is affecting all my view and it shows just a white screen

Comment: @svraluca1 That is likely because the children inside have no constraints. Try putting 5 contianers in their, each with height: 400, width: double.infinity and make them different colors. You'll see it works in that scenario because all the children are bounded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have many other things scrollable you can look at slivers in flutter.
I believe they are a good fit for this.